# Java Loop from user input to repeat process?

Tags: java, loops

I am very new to Java Programming, I have been given a task to work out from user input the easter date for a given year and then to ask if the user would like to input another year to calculate another easter date. What I don't understand is how to create a loop from the second input box ("Noch eine Berechnung? (J/N)") that repeats the entire process again. My code is this:

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Osterberechnung_ohne_schleife {

 public static void main(String[] args) {


  String sJahrEingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bitte Jahr eingeben:");


  int iJahr = Integer.parseInt(sJahrEingabe);

  int iP = iJahr / 100;
  int iQ = iP / 3;
  int iR = iQ / 4;
  int iX = (15 + iP - iQ - iR) % 30;
  int iY = (iP + 4 - iR) % 7;
  int iA = iJahr % 19;
  int iB = iJahr % 4;
  int iC = iJahr % 7;
  int iD = (19 * iA + iX) % 30;
  int iE = (2 * iB + 4 * iC + 6 * iD + iY) % 7;



  if ((iD == 29) && (iE == 6)) {

   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am 19.April");

  } else if ((iD == 28) && (iE == 6)) {

   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am 18.April");

  } else if ((22 + iD + iE) <= 31) {

   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am " + (22 + iD + iE) + ".März");

  } else {

   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am " + (iD + iE - 9) + ".April");

  }

  {

   String sNochJahr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Noch eine Berechnung? (J/N)");

  }


 }

}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Try putting your whole code in a WHILE loop. If user enters 'N', then break out of that loop

Comment: Put the code that does the computation in a function, then create a loop that will call it as long as then answer is `J`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Surround your code with a `do...while` loop and keep going as long as `sNochJahr` is `J`.

```
do {
...
} while (sNochJahr.equals("J"));
```

or while `sNochJahr` is *not* `N`.

```
while (!sNochJahr.equals("N"));
```

Comment: I tried to put the whole code into a do...while loop, however the while sNochJahr cannot be resolved because the sNochjahr variable is within the do...while code. What i don't understand is how to make the do...while loop determined by the user input within the code.

Comment: do {
 if ((iD==29) && (iE==6)) {   
   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am 19.April");   
  } else if ((iD==28) && (iE==6)) {   
   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am 18.April");
   
  } else if ((22 +iD + iE) <= 31) {   
   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am " + (22 + iD + iE) + ".März");   
  } else {   
   System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am " + (iD + iE - 9) + ".April");   
  }  
  String sNochJahr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Noch eine Berechnung? (J/N)"); 
 } while(sNochJahr.equals("J"));  
}
 }

Comment: Copy the code from that link there. Don't mind the error it's showing on that site; it's to do with `JOptionPane`.

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked. Thanks for explaining, I understand now what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Youre saving the response of the user in `String sNochJahr`, but not evaluating it. I would suggest something like this:

```
String sNochJahr = "J"

while (sNochJahr.equals("J")) {
      String sJahrEingabe = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Bitte Jahr eingeben:");


    int iJahr = Integer.parseInt(sJahrEingabe);

    int iP = iJahr / 100;
    int iQ = iP / 3;
    int iR = iQ / 4;
    int iX = (15 + iP - iQ - iR)%30;
    int iY = (iP + 4 - iR)%7;
    int iA = iJahr % 19;
    int iB = iJahr % 4;
    int iC = iJahr % 7;
    int iD = (19 * iA + iX)%30;
    int iE = (2 * iB + 4 * iC + 6 * iD + iY)%7;



    if ((iD==29) && (iE==6)) {

        System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am 19.April");

    } else if ((iD==28) && (iE==6)) {

        System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am 18.April");

    } else if ((22 +iD + iE) <= 31) {

        System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am " + (22 + iD + iE) + ".März");

    } else {

        System.out.println("Ausgabe: Ostern ist am " + (iD + iE - 9) + ".April");

    }

    {

    String sNochJahr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Noch eine Berechnung? (J/N)");

        }
}
```

If the user inputs "N" then, the code breaks out of the while-loop.